# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') how can I resolve this issue in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, router

> The warning in the terminal is based on undefined (reading 'use')-introduced route in my app is app>router>routers.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = require("express").Router();
const { authRouters } = require("./Auth");
const { projectRouters } = require("./Project");
const { teamRouters } = require("./Team");
const { userRouters } = require("./User");
router.use("/project", projectRouters);
router.use("/team", teamRouters);
router.use("/user", userRouters);
router.use("/Auth", authRouters);
module.exports = { AllRouters: router };
```

> Team.js (similarly for Project.js, Auth.js, User.js)

```
const router = require("express").Router();


> my codes...


module.exports = { projectRouters: router };
```

> and finally in my Server.js

```
createRoutes() {
this.#app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  return res.json({ message: "Welcome to my app" });
});
this.#app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  try {
    this.#app.use(AllRouters);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

}

Comment: That is telling you that `router` is undefined.

Comment: I defined in and into its related file named Team.js and included:             
 const router = require("express").Router();
// codes here//
module.exports = { teamRouters: router };

Comment: If you could edit the question to add the relevant code, I'll take a look.

Comment: ok, ill do it. thank you in advance.

Comment: I see `.use` called in 5 places.  Try adding a console.log before them to see what the values `this.#app` and `router` actually have.

Comment: Thank you for your direction. actually, it returns Undefined ?!

Comment: Thank you "Joe" for your time

Answer (score 0):

> To whom may face a similar warning: the root of the problem is a
> matter of not defining " AllRouters" method in the contractor of the
> Server.js and the solution is :

```
module.exports = class Application {
  #app = express();
  #PORT;
  #DB_URL;
  #AllRouters;
  constructor(PORT, DB_URL, AllRouters) {
    this.#PORT = PORT;
    this.#DB_URL = DB_URL;
    this.#AllRouters = AllRouters;
    this.ConfigApplication();
    this.ConnectToMongoDb();
    this.CreateServer();
    this.CreateRoutes();
    this.ErrorHandler();
  }
```